# Basic Global State with React Hooks in React Native

Tags: react-native, redux, state, react-hooks, react-context

I've been jumping on the [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) bandwagon and decided to roll a React Native app together to try and give a full redux/global state implementation a shot. I've been following some articles on how to go about it, but I do have some questions.

I understand the concepts of `useState` and `useReducer`, but I'm getting hung up on the `Context` side of things.

First question: **What is the best way to pass a state object down the tree without having to use props?** Here's what I have so far. Normally, without Navigation, you would have a child component of `DispatchContext` that would receive props. But since I do have Navigation, I don't really want to pass the state down the tree. I feel that defeats the purpose of Context and hooks in general. I've seen some things where the `value={dispatch}` is `value={{somePieceOfState}}`. How can I pass both the state and the dispatch into the component tree?

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import Navigation from './Navigation';
import { DispatchContext } from './Context';
import { countReducer } from './reducers';

const App = () => {
  const [count, dispatchCount] = useReducer(countReducer, 0);

  const dispatch = action => [dispatchCount].forEach(fn => fn(action)); //provides one dispatch for the entire component tree

  const state = {
      count,
      //other pieces of state go here
  }

  return (
    <DispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
      <Navigation />
      // <ChildComponent someStateProp={count} /> normal way to pass down props
    </DispatchContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Second question: **What's the best way to do actions and action creators?** This is probably able to be answered in conjunction with the first question. Here is a component attached to my navigation.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { DispatchContext } from './Context';
import { countUp, countDown } from './actions';

const Comp1 = () => {
  const dispatch = useContext(DispatchContext);
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => dispatch(countUp)}
      >
        <Text>Up</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => dispatch(countDown)}
      >
        <Text>Down</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Comp1;
```

The actions associated with it:

```
import {
  COUNT_UP,
  COUNT_DOWN
} from './types';

export const countUp = () => {
  return {
    type: COUNT_UP
  };
};

export const countDown = () => {
  return {
    type: COUNT_DOWN
  };
};
```

And the reducer:

```
import {
  COUNT_UP,
  COUNT_DOWN
} from '../actions/types';

export const countReducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action) {
    case COUNT_UP:
      return state + 1;
    case COUNT_DOWN:
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I know the actions and dispatch and all that works because I `console.log()` in my reducer and I get a response. But when I `console.log(action)`, it shows that it's the function, the action itself instead of the type. If I `console.log(action.type)`, it's undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

Last question: **Is this a reasonable approach for complex state management?** I know about `useEffect()` and stuff like that, but from anyone that has had some experience with hooks, is it good for api calls and location tracking and stuff like that? Is it an extensible approach? Basically what I'm asking is I don't want to get knee deep into this and have to refactor everything into class-based components because I can't do something with hooks that I need to do with classes. But I really like this hooks thing and I want to stick with it. Is it good to move forward with it?

Sorry for the long post, but I feel these questions that have answers would be useful for others that are looking to get into hooks with react native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that you are confusing an *action creator* with an *action*. An action creator, as the name implies, creates an action when it is invoked. In your case, you are dispatching an action creator instead of dispatching an action. You must invoke the function first.

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => dispatch(countUp())}
>
// ...
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => dispatch(countDown())}
>
```

In the above rework, the action creators are invoked `()` before being passed to dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplified global state management with this small library which written in React Hooks

```
yarn add @rawewhat/stora
```

then just use it like this

```
import useStora from '@rawewhat/stora'

const [states, actions] = useStora()

states.yourState
actions.yourAction()
```

Answer (score 0):

Many existing global hook libraries for React bundles React inside it, or modifies it.

In addition, I didn't like the way that they all seem to rely on "strings" as keys, and lack TypeScript strong-typing.

I just wanted something simple with no magical stuff that might break all the time, or leak memory.

So I wrote my own. Check the source - it's super simple:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fluffy-spoon/react-globalize

## Usage

First, you need to globally create a key for your state, with an optional initial value.

```js
//users.ts

import { createGlobal } from '@fluffy-spoon/react-globalize';

export const usersKey = createGlobal([{ firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" }]);
```

Then, you can simply use it in one of your components, just like you would use `useState`!

```js
//index.ts

import { usersKey } from './users';

export const GlobalUserListComponent = () => {

    //users and setUsers behaves like useState, except they are now shared between all components!
    const [users, setUsers] = useGlobal(usersKey);

    ...
}
```